# Network configuration issue: domain resolving to wrong IP address on M1 MacBook Pro

Tags: dns, ip, ping, arp

I have a strange network configuration issue on my M1 MacBook Pro running macOS Ventura 13.2.1.

When I try to ping or access the my development domain example.com (domain is an example, dns settings are set to 127.0.0.1), it resolves to the wrong IP address of 198.18.2.1, instead of the expected address of 127.0.0.1. This is causing issues with my local development environment. Oddly enough, on other devices on the same network with the same DNS settings, the domain resolves to the correct IP address of 127.0.0.1.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what else I could try to troubleshoot this issue? Could there be any system settings or configurations that are affecting this?

Thanks in advance for any help or insights you can provide.

I have tried the following:

- Flushing the DNS cache using `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`
- Restarting the mDNSResponder service using `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
- Checking for any custom network configurations in the Network preferences pane (none found)

I also tried running the `arp` command on the terminal to see the ARP cache, but it still shows the wrong IP address. `nslookup` gives the correct address.

Comment: Did you look at your `/etc/hosts`? Did you look at the output of `scutil --dns`? If that name to address mapping isn't in `/etc/hosts`, then seeing how your scoped DNS is set up via `scutil --dns` will give you a clue where that address is coming from. It might be a VPN configuration you've installed, for instance.

Comment: Also note that address block 198.18/16 is reserved for multi-subnet router performance benchmarking, in case that's a clue, like maybe you installed a network performance testing tool at some point? Or you set up something on your router for a performance test? Might be a clue.

Comment: That was the first thing I did. There are no lines that modify that domain name. I've compared the results of `scutil --dns` and I do have an extra resolver. I've no idea how to remove that one resolver. flushing the cache does not remove that resolver. the problem still exists when I connect to another network like my home network or a hotspot from my phone.

Comment: the problem was solved by emptying the `/private/etc/resolver`
There was a file there with the name of the domain and as contents `nameserver 127.0.01`. removing this file fixes the problem